# Варианты реализации прокрутки к оставленному на странице комментарию

Tags: ajax, javascript

Подскажите, как проще реализовать переход к оставленному комментарию.

У комментариев свой id, форма выводится через ajax.

Сейчас при оставлении комментария перебрасывает на верх страницы. Какие есть варианты:

**Открытие формы**

```
function openbox(id){
    display = document.getElementById(id).style.display;

    if(display=='none'){
       document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
    }else{
       document.getElementById(id).style.display='none';
    }
}
```

**Вывод формы**

```
$.ajax({  
    url: "/reply/12}",  
    cache: false,  
    success: function(html){  
    $("#block-12").html(html);  
    }  
});

<a href="#" onclick="openbox('box-12'); return false" title="Ответ"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a>
<div id="box-12" style="display: none;"><div id="block-12"></div></div>
```

Comment: @evanto, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("id комментария").offset().top }, 500);
```

Как вам такой вариант? После `$("#block-12").html(html);` вставьте указанный выше код, и он проскроллит до нужного вам комментария.